# A tricky but silly doubt regarding the solutions of $x^2/(y-1)^2=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

**Motivation :**

I have been confused with some degree 2 equation. I suddenly came across a simple equation and couldn't get the quintessence behind that. 
I have an equation $$\dfrac{x^2}{(y-1)^2}=1 \tag{1}$$ and I was looking for its solutions. It was asked by some kid ( of $9$nth standard ) to me. 
I did some manipulation and got $$x^2=(y-1)^2 \tag{2} $$ finally. And one can see that $(0,1)$ satisfies the Equation $[2]$ well. But I was happy, and within small time, 
I realized that the same solution set can't satisfy the equation $[1]$ . If you substitute $(0,1)$ in $[1]$ you get $\dfrac{0}{0}=1$ which is wrong.

**The  answer that convinced me finally :**

We can see the same equation as this $x^2. \dfrac{1}{(y-1)^2}=1$ . We know that the set  of integers form a ring. So the product of two numbers is one if one number is the inverse of other number. '$1$' present on the R.H.S is the identity element. So the product of the entity with its inverse always gives us the identity.

So when $x$ is $0$, the $0$ doesn't have an inverse in the integers. So the case is to be emitted.

**Still persisting questions :**

But the thing that makes me surprise is that the Wolfram Alpha gives me this solution . 
                   [image]

In the picture you can clearly see that they both intersect at $(0,1)$ . But what is that confusion ? 
We omitted that solution, but in fact $(0,1)$ is the intersection of the two lines.

**Questions that are to be answered by learned people :**

- What is the value of term $\dfrac{0}{0}$ ? Isn't it $1$ ?
- Why  the solution pair $(0,1)$  satisfies $x^2=(y-1)^2$ but not $\dfrac{x^2}{(y-1)^2}=1$ ? We know that both of them are manifestations of each other in a simple manner.
- If we need to omit that solution, why do the lines intersect at $(0,1)$ ?

Thank you everyone for giving your time.

Comment: Omit, not emit. 0/0 is undefined in $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb C$. People and machines often ignore [removable singularities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity) (by which I mean fill in the missing point without discussion).

Comment: If it's "tricky", then that precludes it being "silly", no?

Comment: @RahulNarain : Thank you for your edit.

Comment: @anon : Thank you, I always have trouble with homophones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equations $$x^2=(y-1)^2\tag{1}$$ and $$\frac{x^2}{(y-1)^2}=1\tag{2}$$ do not have the same solution set. Every solution of $(2)$ is a solution of $(1)$, but $\langle 0,1\rangle$ is a solution of $(1)$ that is not a solution of $(2)$, because $\frac00$ is undefined.

The reason is that $(1)$ does not imply $(2)$. Note first that $(2)$ **does** imply $(1)$, because you can multiply both sides of $(2)$ by $(y-1)^2$ to get $(1)$. In order to derive $(2)$ from $(1)$, however, you must divide both sides of $(1)$ by $(y-1)^2$, and this is permissible **if and only if** $(y-1)^2\ne 0$. Thus, $(1)$ and $(2)$ are equivalent **if and only if** $(y-1)^2\ne 0$. As long as $(y-1)^2\ne 0$, $(1)$ and $(2)$ have exactly the same solutions, but a solution of $(1)$ with $(y-1)^2=0$ need not be (and in fact isn’t) a solution of $(2)$.

As far as the graphs go, the solution of $(1)$ is the union of the straight lines $y=x+1$ and $y=-x+1$. The solution of $(2)$ consists of every point on these two straight lines **except** their point of intersection.

Comment: Thank you. It was useful and good. +1.

Comment: @Iyengar: You’re welcome; I’m glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram Alpha sometimes does that. It's a little bit finicky. You can see that [if we ask it for the domain](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+x%5E2%2F%28y-1%29%5E2) of $z=\frac{x^2}{(y-1)^2}$, it does indeed have us omit the case where $y=0$. I've observed this behaviour lots—for instance if you [ask it to plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y%3D%5Cfrac%7B%28x-1%29%5E2%7D%7B%28x-1%7D%29) $y=\frac{(x-1)^2}{x-1}$, you get a similar result: it fills in the hole which should exist at $x=1$. However when you [ask it for the domain of that function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=domain+of+f%28x%29%3D%5Cfrac%7B%28x-1%29%5E2%7D%7B%28x-1%7D%29), it gives the correct domain. I think that this is evidence of a tradeoff between having something which interprets natural language, and having something that's precise.

Comment: It was really good one. +1

Answer (score 2):

You cannot multiply both side of an equation with $0$. When you multiply your equation by $(y-1)^2$, you are assuring that you are not taking $y=1$ as a valid solution.

Comment: Thank you, it was nice .+1.

Answer (score 2):

Two points which might help.

- $0/0$ is undefined
- you are not allowed to multiply an equation by 0 (if you do so then you increase the set of solutions)

So [1] is equivalent to [2] iff $y\neq 1$.

The solutions to your equation [1] thus read
$$ x =\pm (y-1), \qquad y\neq1.$$

Comment: Thank you for your information. +1.